# How to build debug mode with GCP's appengine(golang:1.15)

Tags: go, google-app-engine, goland

I tried to build debug mode with GCP's appengine.
But, I can't build with debug mode.
Below command is success!(normal build)

```
dev_appserver.py --port=8083 dir/app.yaml
```

But, below command is failed.(add --go_debugging=yes [options])

```
dev_appserver.py --port=8083 --go_debugging=yes dir/app.yaml
```

I use Go1.15 runtime.
I want to use debug...
My IDE is GoLand.

Below is my error.

```
INFO     2023-02-13 05:32:17,620 devappserver2.py:316] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2023-02-13 05:32:17,882 <string>:383] Starting API server at: http://localhost:57209
INFO     2023-02-13 05:32:17,884 instance_factory.py:185] Building with dependencies from go.mod.
INFO     2023-02-13 05:32:17,998 dispatcher.py:281] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2023-02-13 05:32:18,001 admin_server.py:150] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
ERROR    2023-02-13 05:32:19,104 instance_factory.py:250] Failed to build Go application: (Executed command: go build -gcflags "all=-N -l" -o /var/folders/74/8b3cryt139z32p36jnwgm_3h0000gp/T/tmpQH97W4appengine-go-bin/_ah_exe .)


invalid value "\"all=-N -l\"" for flag -gcflags: parameter may not start with quote character "
usage: go build [-o output] [build flags] [packages]
Run 'go help build' for details.

WARNING  2023-02-13 05:32:19,107 instance.py:297] Could not get PID of instance
ERROR    2023-02-13 05:32:19,107 instance.py:300] '_GoBuildFailureRuntimeProxy' object has no attribute '_process'
```

Please some advice for me.

I want to debug with appengine and Go1.15.

Comment: I tried your command and it worked for me. Then I checked source code for ```instance_factory``` and you're getting an error for the following ```if self._go_application.maybe_build(self._modified_since_last_build)``` . It seems that GAE only tries to (re)build if something has changed ```...if any files in the application root or the GOPATH have changed since the last call to maybe_build```. Did you change anything before you tried calling ```dev_appserver.py``` with ```--go_debugging```?